When execute multiple ajax function in async way. PHP response in sync way
Here show js function, But my response received from PHP which is in sequence. So I expecting queries to execute all in one go.
PHP queries
public function get_filtered_data_01(){...}
public function get_filtered_data_02(){...}

JS query
//Example ajax query 01 as like below we have few more query
    function load_filtered_data_1(data_params) {
        $.ajax({.....});
    }
    async function loadAllFilters(data_params) {
        try {
            await Promise.all([
                load_filtered_data_1(data_params),
                load_filtered_data_2(data_params),
                ............
            ]);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error loading filters:", error);
        }
    }
    $('#dropdown').on('change', async function() {
        // Load all other filters concurrently
        await loadAllFilters(data_params);
    });


Most likely it's a session
